# Check for changed field in a Django CBV Update

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a standard CBV Update method for my model `Announcement`:

models.py:

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ...
    draft = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

view.py:

```
class Update(UpdateView):
    model = Announcement
    form_class = AnnouncementForm
    template_name = 'announcements/form.html'

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Update, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs
```

Using this CBV `Update`, how can I check if the boolean `draft` field was changed, and if it was, do stuff?

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with:

```
if 'value' in form.changed_data:
```

where:

- `form` is your `AnnouncementForm` and has been validated first (`form.is_valid`)
- `value` is the field name

Since you're using CBV, you can put the logic in `form_valid` method, to make sure all the data is properly validated (unless you have a different use case)

Comment: Can you help me with the proper way to call form_valid? I'm struggling with these CBVs

Comment: @43Tesseracts Can you please specify what exactly you have a problem with?